# Spring Boot Query - return list of objects with nested list of objects

Tags: spring-boot

I wonder if it's possible to return list of objects A where object A can have list of objects B - there is a separate table B with foreign key to the main table A. Is it possible?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NEW(some dto) FROM A a " +
            "JOIN B b ON a.linkToB.id = b.id " +
            "WHERE a.isActive = true " +
            "AND a.shipper.id = :companyId")
    List<ABC> findAllActiveTempl(@Param("companyId") Long companyId);
```

```
@Entity
public class A{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_basic", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Boolean isBasic;



...
}


public class B 

    @Column(updatable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

  ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_b"))
    @ToString.Exclude
    private B b;
```

Or maybe the only way to fetch List of B objects is a second query?

I need to receive List that contains nested List. How to do that in a most efficient way?

Comment: Could you share your Java code, how you structure `class A` and `class B`?

Comment: @TrietDoan added

Comment: Is there a typo in the end? If you use `@ManyToOne`, then the declaration should be `private A a`, or?

Comment: And where is `shipper`? Is it part of `class A`?

Comment: shipper is not important... Table B has foreign key to Table A.. Shipper is only in Table A but not in DTO A (unnecessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, just need to declare `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` properly to make sure that the relationship is bidirectional.

For example, you have 2 classes, `Book` and `Library` (`B` and `A` in your case, respectively), and a relationship saying "one library can have many books". The scenario can be modelled like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
        
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="library_id")
    private Library library;
    
    // other columns...
}

public class Library {
 
    //...
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "library")
    private List<Book> books;
 
    //...
 
}
```

Make sure that you have `@OneToMany` declared in the `Library` class. The repository can be simply like this:

```java
List<Library> findLibraryByName(String name);
```

After calling the `findLibraryByName`, you can loop through the returned list and access the `books` variable of each `library`.

Comment: Yes! Its so easy:) I just wanted to not touch my A entity but I think it's the best way to get list of A objects with nested List with B objects